# Android Retrofit GET call response is NULL

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit2

Hi i have google this issue for last 8 to 9 hrs. Actually i m not able to find the what is the mistake i am doing here.

I have two network calls . One is login. It is working fine. I am using Retrofit.

But i have another network call. It is not working as expected. I am getting the response as null through my code is i execute the call in chrome , I am getting the response. Fine below is my code. and please help me where i am doing wrong.

build gradle

```
//retrofit for networkcall
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.0-RC1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

ApiClient.java

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = Constants.BASE_URL;
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        //OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

ApiInterface.java

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(Constants.TOKEN_URL)
    Call<Token> getToken(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password, @Field("grant_type") String grant_type);

    @GET(Constants.GET_VEHICLE_BRAND_COUN_TLIST_URL) // here is method i am trying to call in my activity class.
    Call<JSONArray> getVehicleBrandCountList();
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
private void getLoggedInUserData( String bearerToken) {
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<JSONArray> call = apiService.getVehicleBrandCountList();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONArray> call, Response<JSONArray> response) {
            try{
                Log.e("body---",response.body().toString());
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONArray> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(this + "-----", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do have any other information？I guess your server not work when you call the API.

Comment: the issue is with one special character in url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the endPoint in the image with a browser and it seems it sends back a XML response and not JSON. But from Postman (software to test API calls) it seems it can send you back a response in JSON format.

Try adding a "Accept" header to your GET call, to indicate the format in which you want to receive the response.

```
 @Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
 @GET(Constants.GET_VEHICLE_BRAND_COUN_TLIST_URL) // here is method i am trying to call in my activity class.
    Call<JSONArray> getVehicleBrandCountList();
}
```